# Using external js and css in polymer element

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a Polymer element that uses an external js and css.  I invoke a js function on dom ready.  It works fine in Chrome.
In Firefox 47.0 and IE Edge, it doesnt work as expected.  In both these cases, the cvtable.css in the code below is not downloaded in Firefox and IE.
In Firefox, the js function window.cvtable.createTable() gets called; but in IE it doesnt even get called.

Thanks

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/cis/css/cvtable.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cis/js/cvtable.js"></script>

<dom-module id="cis-home-index-perf-table">
  <template>
    <div id="indices_perf_div" class="debug" style="float:left;clear:none;overflow:auto;width:813px;height:250px;">
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'cis-home-index-perf-table',
      ready: function () {
        var fundDetailsJSON =
          '"some json":"some json value"';
        $(document).ready(function () {
          window.cvtable.createTable(fundDetailsJSON);
        });
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debugging, this turned out to be an issue where i had not closed the div in the template.  I was using Brackets IDE, and it never indicated a missing closing tag.  Need some ways to handle these issues.